# Is BerkeleyDb the right in-process database for my project?

Tags: database, berkeley-db

I am writing a C# application, which will possibly move to C++ in the medium term, and need a database to persist a few thousand rows of data.  I want an in-process database as this is going to be rolled out to a remote client who I won't be able to support easily.  I was thinking that BerkeleyDb is usually the canonical choice for this sort of requirement, but wondered if anything better had come on to the scene in the last few years.  Any recommendations or comments?

Comment: erhm.. you haven't told what your project is about. mind reading is not one of my skills

Answer (score 0):

There is no "right answer".  I'd look (at least briefly!) at ALL the major candidates.  Including:

- [BerkleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)
- [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/)
- [MSSQL Embedded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142) (aka "SQL Server Compact")

Comment: I'm going to use SQLite, to avoid any licensing issues.